# Mixamo Animations not working correctly in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mixamo

HI I'm following CodeMonkeys third person shooter tutorial in unity however when I use the same pistol idle animation he used it seems to render differetly for me, in his tutorial the animation loads perfectly but in mine the animation with the default settings seem to be rotated in the wrong direction and the pose is altered a little which makes it look weird, the strangest part is that there is no issue in the animation itself, it uses all the standard settings

I think this might have something to do with the fact that I'm using the third person controller and it might be some sort of weird inverse kinematics issue but I'm not sure all I'm doing is playing an animation on the third person controller

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem maybe in the avatar configuration, check you could use A-pose instead of T-pose or A-pose instead of T-pose. Check your avatar configuration.

Comment: HI thanks for responding, I don't have any avatar mask/configuration setup for the Unity Third Person controller I just replaced the standard animations is all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).